# ¿Cómo solucionar problemas con instalación de paquetes en Rstudio?

Tags: rstudio

He intentado instalar el paquete dplyr, al parecer corre bien pero al momento de llamarlo con library me arroja un error

`install.packages("dplyr") library("dplyr") Error in library("dplyr") : there is no package called ‘dplyr`

Por favor si alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo lo agradecería enormemente
gracias